# Passing a thunk to puppeteer's $.eval

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

The function `setValue` receives a value and returns a function. Inside the second function I'm trying to console log the value of `value` but I get

```
Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: value is not defined
```

My code bellow. It can be tested on [try-puppeteer](https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/), just copy and paste my code and remove the `require` statement.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const USERNAME = 'helloworld';
  const setValue = (value) => (input) => { console.log(value) };

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('http://example.com');
  await page.$eval('.selector', setValue(USERNAME));

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a problem that is common to any library that is executed in Node.js and evaluates code in browser (Protractor, TestCafe, Nightmare, etc). A function is stringified and passed to a browser as a string. Original scope of `(input) => { console.log(value) }` is lost, and `value` is expected to be a global, which is undefined.

As [the documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frameevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) mentions, additional arguments are supposed to be passed to `$eval`.

It should be:

```
await page.$eval('.selector', (el, value) => { console.log(value) }, USERNAME);
```

`console.log` will work but obviously, won't display anything in Node console, because it refers to browser console.