# nodejs: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, puppeteer

There are similar questions on stackoverflow but none helped me with this. What is wrong with my code? Why is it exiting with `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: target_time is not defined`. Where should I declare the variable so that it becomes global?

Here is the code

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// const target_time = 1640955540;

async function getexample(){
  const target_time = 1640955540;
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const url = "https://example.com";
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitForSelector("h1");

  const date_change = await page.$eval("h1", e =>
       e.innerHTML = target_time   // This is where the exception occurs
   );
  console.log(date_change);
  console.log(target_time)
  await browser.close();
};

getexample();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657830/passing-a-thunk-to-puppeteers-eval). I have to pass my variable to the $eval function. Finally my code becomes.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// const target_time = 1640955540;

async function getexample(){
  const target_time = 1640955540;
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const url = "https://example.com";
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitForSelector("h1");

  await page.$eval("h1", (e,t) =>
       e.innerHTML = target_time   // This is where the exception used to occur
   ,target_time); // I had to remove the return `date_change` because it returned undefined.
  //console.log(date_change);
  console.log(target_time)
  await browser.close();
};

getexample();
```