# How to iterate over a table and then hover on a particular row having a given column value in puppeteer?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, puppeteer, ui-automation

The table is having columns as given below:

```
| Organization  | Username      | Option                           |
____________________________________________________________________
| Helloworld    | username1     | delete icon appear here on hover |
| Stackoverflow | test          | delete icon appear here on hover |
| Puppeteer     | username2     | delete icon appear here on hover |
____________________________________________________________________
```

I want to iterate over the table and hover over the option to click on the delete icon for the column having Username value = test.

How can I achieve this using puppeteer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)s on the specific columns (if the column numbers are known, as in your example), it can be iterated over on the rows of the table something like this:

```js
const numberOfRows = await page.$$eval('table > tbody > tr', rows => rows.length)

for (let n = 1; n < numberOfRows + 1; n++) {
  const currentUser = `table > tbody > tr:nth-child(${n}) > td:nth-child(2)` // nth row 2nd column
  const currentOption = `table > tbody > tr:nth-child(${n}) > td:nth-child(3)` // nth row 3rd column

  const currentUserString = await page.$eval(currentUser, el => el.innerText)

  if (currentUserString === 'test') {
    try {
      await page.hover(currentOption)
      await page.click(currentOption)
    } catch {}
  }
}
```

[`Page.hover`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pagehoverselector) and [`page.click`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pageclickselector-options) can be used on the 3rd columns' `td`s to achieve the user removals. This part of the code depends on the actual page's behavior.

Comment: Hey @theDavidBarton! this line ```const currentUserString = await page.$eval(currentUser, el => el.innerText)``` is giving ```Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: cov_218kt0db29 is not defined``` , do you have any idea why?

Comment: (1) If you are using Jest (or any other testing libraries relies on Istanbul) together with puppeteer this issue can occur sometimes, here there are suggestions on how to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272295/using-jest-with-puppeteer-evaluation-failed-referenceerror-cov-4kq3tptqc-is; (2) if you try to pass a variable outside of the `$eval`'s scope, you should pass it as an argument: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657830/passing-a-thunk-to-puppeteers-eval (but if you followed my suggestion above it is not likely to be the cause of the issue). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, @theDavidBarton! I got it!